# Python packaging: handle dependency from non-Python libraries

Tags: python, cmake, dependency-management, pypi

A Python package I'm currently working on has the following dependencies:

- a C++ library (which is included in the source files of the package)
- Google's protobuf & protoc
- cmake

The package can be found at https://github.com/bayesmix-dev/pybmix

The protobuf library is needed both for the C++ library (internal data exchange) and for the Python/C++ interface (C++ passes to python serialized protobuf objects and Python de-serializes them).

Basically, in the setup.py the following operations are performed:

- cmake is invoked to compile a pybind11 python package, that is a wrapper of the C++ library. The pybind11 package links to protobuf. Also, cmake compiles a bunch of .proto files into the corresponding .pb.h and .pb.cc
- protoc is invoked to compile the same .proto files into the corresponding python classes (further 2to3 is used to handle relative imports of the generated files)

Now, my question is: what is the best way to handle these dependencies in a user-friendly way? My plan is to distribute this package through PyPi, and ideally one should just type

```
pip install pybmix
```

and the setup script would either deal with the dependencies itself or point to the missing libraries.

Comment: were you able to find a way for this ?